# Can't Connect to DelphiXE5 AND SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2012, delphi-xe5

I have a Delphi application that is connected to SQL Server 2012. On my local, I've been able to connect successfully. I've also tried it on another VM, and it work fine. I deployed it on a Server, and it won't connect to the database. I check the connection string; it looks fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

- SQL Server 2012 is installed on a different server
- I can reached the server
- I check the provider and it's using SQLNCI11
- I have SQL Server 2012 Natice Client Install
- I check and make sure that the username/password have access to the database, and they can login

What am I missing here?

Comment: Thank you Sir Rufo. I edit the question and added the tags.

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: The issue had to do with my provider. The ADO Connection was point sqlncli10.dll, I made the changes as Uwe suggested,and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that you can change the vendor lib in the provider, that change will have no effect as the name of the DLL is hard-coded into the provider. It will try to use sqlncli10.dll, no matter what the property is.

Install sqlncli10.dll and it should work.